# How do Brownian/Wiener processes involve randomness?

Tags: statistics, brownian-motion, finance

My financial mathematics course notes have

> A Brownian motion is a family of random variables $\{B_t|t\geq0\}$ on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ such that: \begin{align}
> (1) \; & B_0=0, \\
> (2) \; & \text{for } 0\leq s\leq t \text{ the increment } B_t-B_s \text{ is normally distributed} \\ 
> & \text{with mean } 0 \text{ and variance } t-s, \\
> (3) \; & \text{for any } 0\leq t_1<t_2<\dots<t_n \text{ the increments } \\
> & \hspace{1em} B_{t_1}-B_0,B_{t_2}-B_{t_1},\dots,B_{t_n}-B_{t_{n-1}} \\
> & \text{are independent random variables, and} \\
> (4) \; & \text{For any } \omega \in \Omega \text{ the function } t\mapsto B_t(\omega) \text{ is continuous.}
> \end{align} [image]

I interpret the numbered $\omega$'s in the images (low res in the original) to mean that a Wiener process/Brownian motion is typically (for this context) taken over a fixed $\omega$. What I then wonder is: where does the randomness come from?

To try to understand better, I found [these](https://www.newbooks-services.de/MediaFiles/Texts/4/9781441916044_Excerpt_001.pdf) notes, which have

> The space of elementary events for the Brownian motion is the set of all continuous real functions, $$\Omega=\{\omega(t):\mathbb{R}_+\mapsto\mathbb{R}\}.$$

and

> **Random functions:** For each $t\geq0$ consider the random variable $X_t(\omega)=\omega(t)\in\Omega$. This random variable is the outcome of the experiment of sampling the position of a Brownian particle (trajectory) at a fixed time $t$. Thus $X_t(\omega)$ takes different values on different trajectories.

If $\omega$ is any continuous, real-valued function, shouldn't a sequence of such experiments on a fixed $\omega$ sometimes produce constant-valued curves?

Comment: Yes, the sample space is the set of continuous functions. But what is the probability measure associated with it? It is the Wiener measure, which should answer your question.

Comment: @Andrew OK, if I'm understanding [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1454263/596895) right, the Wiener  measure says (very informally) that the sort of function we want (i.e. those satisfying properties 1-4) has non-zero probability of being chosen, and the others have zero probability. Understanding the Wiener measure in more detail [seems](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Wiener_measure) to involve understanding Borel sets, which I don't.

Comment: The probability theory only attempts to formalize how we deal with patterns or uncertainty in random samples. It does not tell anything about how the randomness should be generated. So, unlike the name "random variable" or "random function" or whatsoever, there is no randomness in the theory itself. A random variable more or less describes a particular information processing.

Comment: Going in line with Sangchul Lee's comment, one of the if not the most important probability space is $([0,1],\lambda,\mathcal{B})$. So infact, "all" (measurable) functions from $[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ are "random variables". That means $\sin(x):[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ is a random variable. Now I ask you, is there anything inherently random about $\sin$? No. So I like to phrase Probability theory as being the deterministic way to model randomness. So the distribution is where the modelling of "probability" or the notion of chance comes in.

Comment: Wiener measure precisely gives a way to model the "chance" that the brownian motion falls in the collection (Borel subset) of particular kinds continuous functions. This is what is meant by $P((B)_{t}\in A)$ for $A\subset C[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Would you mind defining $\lambda,\mathcal{B}$, and saying something about how you get that all measurable functions from $[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are random variables? That sounds like something I'd like to understand. If you've actually already told me, would you mind saying it a bit differently? because I haven't got it.

Comment: $\lambda$ means the Lebesgue measure and $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel sigma algebra. You see that random variables $X$ are $\mathcal{F}$ measurable functions from a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ to $\Bbb{R}$. By measurable, I mean that $X^{-1}(A)=\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in A)\}\in\mathcal{F}$ for all $A$ which are borel subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ (for simplicity consider any subset of $\Bbb{R}$. And $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)$ is perhaps THE most important probability space. To know more, I would suggest that you read a preliminary chapter of a probability theory book like Durrett.

Comment: @mjc Hence, in all sense of the term, all functions (measurable) from $[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ are technically random variables. I say all functions because non-measurable functions are not that easy to construct(usually only geniuses like Sierpinski,Banach, Tarski or Vitali were/are able to create such functions and they are highly abstract, but they do exist). So there's nothing inherently random about random variables. It is only when you view $P(X\in A)$, (i.e. the distribution) , that you associate a "chance" or probability of $X$ lying in $A$ and this is how randomness is modelled.